# How to get server token for Uber?

Tags: uber-api

[UBER dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0S3M.png)Where can I get my Uber server token? I have created an account and got a `Client Id` and a `Client secret`. But I can't find server token on my developer account.

Answer (score 0):

When you log into the [dashboard](https://developer.uber.com/dashboard) you will see a list of all of your apps. Select whatever app you are looking to use. Then under "Authentication & Security" where you see the Client ID and Client Secret, on the right hand side there should be a "Server Token" that you can use.

Comment: Edited my question to show dashboard screen, I can't find any server token on right side to Client ID and Client Secret.

Comment: Hmm. Weird. It shows up on my app and shows up when I create a new app. It's a Rides API app, right? If it's not too much trouble I'd try making a new app and seeing if it shows up that way.

Comment: I also just created an app and I get the following message at the place where the server token should be displayed: "Please reach out to your Uber Business Development representative for server token access.", like other people [here](https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk/issues/267). No idea who this representative is supposed to be or how to contact him though.